# How to make a vertical scroll bar in rhandsontable [Shiny]

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

Could you make a hint how to make a vertical scroll bar in rhandsontable table?
I have not found a clear guidance so far.
The earlier question is [here](https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable/issues/310).

The draft script is here:
**UI side:**

```
column(8,                                              
  rHandsontableOutput("loaded_table")  
)
```

**Server side:**

```
output$loaded_table <- renderRHandsontable({
  if (!is.null(descStat))
    rhandsontable(descStat, maxRows = 20)
})
```

Comment: Could you post a little example code? Because maybe this little CSS could do it `overflow-y: scroll;`

Comment: @SeGa the draft script is added.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't there a vertical scroll by default?

I am seeing one in this example:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(8,
    rHandsontableOutput("loaded_table", height = "200px")
  ) 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$loaded_table <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(iris, maxRows = 20)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: In fact, I have got a horizontal scroll bar but not vertical one. I have removed maxRows property - no vertical scroll bar.

Comment: also without maxRows I am seeing one, as I limited the table to 200px anyway. What version of rhandsontable are you using?

Comment: the package version is rhandsontable_0.3.7
Actually my idea is to make a fixed visible row output but be able to scroll up and down.

Comment: it is strange but your script works fine. I can not understand why my one doesn't.

Comment: I've come here as I've had a similar issue, the above script worked by in my full app `maxRows` didn't help. In the end I used `height = 200` which enabled my scroll bar in the end.